# Creating Multiple values hashtable inside powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, hashtable

I want a hash table with values that are arrays like below. But no luck. I want to get an output like below.

Here is my script:

```
$SKUToGroup= @{} # creates hash table
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users = @() #adds an array
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users += "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users += "0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E1_Users += "18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E1_Users += "0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52"
```

Output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
O365_E1_Users                  18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52
O365_E3_Users                  {6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, 0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52}
```

My desired output:

```
Name                                                                            Value
----                                                                            -----
{18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e, 0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52}     O365_E1_Users
{6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, 0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52}    O365_E3_Users
```

Comment: If I got it right it does not make that much sense I think. Why would you like to have multiple names for the same value?

Comment: I have to use a hashtable like that.

Comment: Sorry if that sounds stubborn - why? You may elaborate a little more detailed. ;-)

Comment: Using combined key names like that wil not make the hash useful as lookup table..

Answer (score 0):

As [@Olaf told](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66929336/creating-multiple-values-hashtable-inside-powershell#comment118307592_66929336): *if I got it right it does not make that much sense*:

```
$SKUToGroup= @{} # creates hash table
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users = @() #adds an array
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users += "6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E3_Users += "0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E1_Users = @()
$SKUToGroup.O365_E1_Users += "18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e"
$SKUToGroup.O365_E1_Users += "0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52"

$SKUToGroupRev = @{}
foreach ($itemKey in $SKUToGroup.Keys) {
    $SKUToGroupRev.$($SKUToGroup.$itemKey) = $itemKey
}
$SKUToGroupRev
```

**Output**: `.\SO\66929336.ps1 | Format-List`

```
Name  : {18181a46-0d4e-45cd-891e-60aabd171b4e, 0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52}
Value : O365_E1_Users

Name  : {6fd2c87f-b296-42f0-b197-1e91e994b900, 0c266dff-15dd-4b49-8397-2bb16070ed52}
Value : O365_E3_Users
```